# Calculating the Log Likelihood of models in glmnet?

Tags: likelihood, glmnet, deviance

glmnet() returns a lambda sequence fitobj$lambda and I would like to calculate the log likelihood of the models (LL_model) defined by the lambda sequence.

The obvious solution is to just take the parameters and calculate the LL of each model manually. However, this not very elegant and very slow. Therefore, I am trying to calculate the LL_model from the deviance-measures that are returned by glmnet.

**the glmnet-object gives me:**

1) nulldev = 2*(LL_sat - LL_null), where LL_sat is the saturated model and LL_null is the NULL model (one value)

2) dev.ratio = 1 - dev.model/nulldev, where dev.model is the deviance of the model at hand (k values, for k lambda values/models)

3) and glmnet:::deviance.glmnet gives me the dev_model = (1-dev.ratio)*nulldev dev.model = 2*(LL_sat - LL_model) (k values for, k lambda values/models)

**To calculate the LL for each model, I would do the following:**

1) Calculate LL_null

2) Solve (1) for LL_sat and calculate LL_sat (one value)

3) solve (3) for LL_model and calculate LL_model (k vector)

**Now, my two questions are:**

1) How is this NULL model defined? The glmnet-manual says "The NULL model refers to the intercept model."  But I am a bit puzzled by the fact that there is only one NULL model and nulldev for the whole lambda sequence. Based on which lambda is this intercept model calculated? I have the feeling I am missing something.

2) Does anybody see an easier way to calculate the LL of each model in the sequence? The final goal is to calculate the (E)BIC of each model. I am surprised by the fact that turns out to be so tedious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For 1), you're missing that the intercept is unregularized, so $\lambda$ has no effect on the calculated intercept.

Comment: thank you! do you have a reference? or is this somehow incredibly obvious?

Comment: It's not obvious, I learned it from this paper: http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6287975.pdf

Comment: well, that would have been the obvious reference ;) thanks for your help!

Comment: Jmb do you have a code to compute the BIC for each model using glmnet procedure ? It would be of great help !

Comment: @remi: The NULL model is just the intercept model, hence it is the same for the whole lambda sequence. The most efficient way to get the Likelihood of each model is hence to calculate the deviance of the NULL model once and then solve for the Likelihood for each model in the lambda sequence.

Comment: @jmb: isn't the deviance of the null model just nulldev?  I'm still unable to solve this since I've only 2 equations but three unknowns.

Comment: @Faller: it is easy to calculate the LL of the null (intercept) model. Together with nulldev from the output you can calculate the LL of the saturated model (nulldev = 2(LLsat - LLnull)). Second you solve dev.ratio=1-dev/nulldev for dev. Finally, you solve dev = 2(LLsat - LLmod) for LLmod, the LL of your given model. I guess this is the fastest way in terms of computations. In terms of nice code, I guess it would be better to just calculate the LL of the models again yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one sure way to compute the log-likelihood of logistic (and probit) regressions, no matter how it is estimated. All you need is the dependent dummy and fitted values.

I tested the function on a model with just a constant and it seems to work well. It is NOT that hard to compute a log likelihood -- so just write it down and compute it by hand. Then, just always use the same function everywhere and your computations will be coherent.

I really don't know why logLik is not yet compatible with glmnet. Penalized pseudo-R2 are often used measures of fit, you need it for information criterion and it just seems more convenient to have that value to compute plenty of test statistics. Anyway, here it is for future reference:

```
 logit_logLik <- function(dummy,fitted_values){
   # Description: Computes log-likelihood of a fitted
   # logit model 

   # Format variables
   y <- as.matrix(dummy)
   p <- as.matrix(fitted_values)
   # Adjust dimensions
   skip <- dim(y)[1] - dim(p)[1]
   y    <- as.matrix(y[-c(1:skip),])

   # Compute log-likelihood
   item <- sapply(1:dim(y)[1], function(i)
                          y[i,]*log(p[i,]) + (1-y[i,])*log(1-p[i,]))
   return(sum(item))
 }
```