# How do you calculate the loglikelihood of a poisson GLM fit with glmnet?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, likelihood, glmnet

I have fit a poisson GLM to some data using glmnet in MATLAB. I would like to calculate the loglikelihood of the model given the data but am struggling to work out how to do that.

I've seen similar questions where the authors are trying to use various deviance outputs of glmnet to derive loglikelihood: ([Calculating the Log Likelihood of models in glmnet?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160019/calculating-the-log-likelihood-of-models-in-glmnet?newreg=177789e72d6a4b4290ebacc92b895495)). But I am not confident I have implemented this correctly:

```
cv_err = cvglmnet(X,y,'poisson','deviance',10);

best_lambda = find(cv_err.lambda == cv_err.lambda_1se);

dev_exp = cv_err.glmnet_fit.dev(best_lambda);

glmnet_fit = cv_err.glmnet_fit;

null_model = fitglm(ones(size(X,1),1),y);

ll_null = null_model.LogLikelihood;

nulldev = glmnet_fit.nulldev;

ll_sat = ll_null + (nulldev/2);

dev = (1 - dev_exp) * nulldev;

ll_model = ll_sat - (dev/2);
```

Is this correct? Or alternatively can someone suggest a more generic way of calculating log-likelihood for any poisson GLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after digging around in the MATLAB GeneralizedLinearModel.m code I have found/ adapted the following:

```
if strmatch('poisson', family)
    ll_model = sum(poisslogpdf(data,pred));
    null_dat = repmat(nanmean(data),size(data,1),1);
    ll_null = sum(poisslogpdf(data,null_dat));
end

function logy = poisslogpdf(x,lambda)
    logy = (-lambda + x.*log(lambda) - gammaln(x+1));
end
```